# Why does the gtest death test loop indefinitely

Tags: c++, googletest

In my project we imitate blockbox testing using gtest. For that reason we implemented a mockMain() function containing all relevant code that should be inside the blackbox. Then we use the TEST_F functions by gtest to execute that main and verify the output it generates. The problem now is: I want to write death tests because for some input made, the program should exit. Unfortunately, the death test loops indefinitely, when I execute it.
Since the actual program is enormous, I tried to capture the essence of what is happening in the following code. It has the same problem as the main program.

I found out on Windows the deathtests are executed int the "threadsafe" mode, which reruns the whole program. Is there a way to change that?

**main.cpp**

```
bool runBlackboxTest = true;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   //Only execute tests if flag is enabled
    if(runBlackboxTest){
        RectangleBlackboxTest::runAllTests();
        exit(0);
    }
    Rectangle oneRect(12.1, 7.4);
    std::cout << "Area: " << oneRect.getArea() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(double a, double b){
    this->side_a = a;
    this->side_b = b;

    this->area = a*b;
}

double Rectangle::getArea(){
    return this->area;
}

double Rectangle::rectExit(){
    std::cout << "Exiting program." << std::endl;
    exit(1); 
    return 0;
}
```

**RectangleBlackboxTest.cpp**

```
using RectangleBlackboxDeathTest = RectangleBlackboxTest;

int RectangleBlackboxTest::runAllTests(){
    testing::InitGoogleTest();
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}

//Just some example functinoality
void RectangleBlackboxTest::mockMain(){
    double a, b;
    srand(time(NULL));
    a = double(rand() % 100 + 1) / 17;
    b = double(rand() % 100 + 1) / 11;
    this->testingRect = new Rectangle(a, b);
    std::cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " Area: " << this->testingRect->getArea() << std::endl;
}

//Imitating an exit in the mockMain()
void RectangleBlackboxTest::mockMainWithExit(){
    this->mockMain();
    this->testingRect->rectExit();
}

void RectangleBlackboxTest::TearDown(){
    delete this->testingRect;
}

//This is the part that loops indefinitely
TEST_F(RectangleBlackboxDeathTest, firstDeathTest){
    EXPECT_EXIT(mockMainWithExit(), testing::ExitedWithCode(1), ".*");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem:

The main problem lies in `testing::InitGoogleTest()`.

When gtest finds a death test, it creates a new process using `createProcessA(...)` under Windows and passes additional parameters, to make sure the child process only executes the current death test.
This leads to problems, when those parameters are not given to `testing::InitGoogleTest()` in the child process. In this case it doesn't receive the information to only execute the death test and starts running the whole test code again, leading to recursion.

TLDR:

Pass the command line arguments from `main(int argc, char *argv[])` to `testing::InitGoogleTest()`:

`testing::InitGoogleTest(argc, argv)`